# VNC over SSH on open Tunnel

Tags: ssh, vnc, ssh-tunnel

Is it possible to bind VNC server to a open SSH tunnel?

I have a tablet that has initiated a reverse ssh tunnel to my server. This works fine over port 8080.

I need to now bind to this port from my local machine. It looks like Ubuntu has some "remote desktop viewier" that has ssh built in capabilities so I assume the only thing I need to do now is figure out how to bind the tablets VNCserver to the open SSH tunnel.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of online guides to tunneling vnc.

Normally, the tunnel would be set up with something like 'ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 remotehost', though it can be set up from the remote host instead.  With it in place, it's just running 'vncviewer localhost:1' instead of 'vncviewer remosthost:1'.

Vnc has assumptions about what the port numbers are...5901 corresponds to display :1, etc.  Local vnc client will expect the near end to be a workable port number, and the remote vnc server will likewise expect the remote port to be usable.

Unless you mean 'ssh remotehost -p 8080' gets you a working shell.  In that case, the '-L' options can possibly be tacked on the end of the '-p' options, to establish a second/separate connection just for vnc, using the first one to channel the authentication of setting it up.